# integration by parts in definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am reading a textbook about ODE and am confused about the following:

$$\int_0^xf'(t)dt =(t-x)f'(t)\bigg\vert_0^x + \int_0^x (x-t)f''(t)dt $$

Obviously, $$u = f'(t)=\frac{df(t)}{dt} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \frac{dv}{dt}=1$$

So $$\int\frac{dv}{dt}dt=\int1 \Rightarrow v=t+c$$

> My question is how to obtain the term $(t-x)$ and $(x-t)$?  In the above derivation, I cannot find this term.

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: $x$ is the constant of integration and $t$ the variable to evaluate at $x$ and $0$

Comment: choosing $t-x$ as the primitive of $1$ instead of just $t$, we have that $$(t-x)f'(t)\bigg\vert_0^x=0$$  when $f'(0)=0$. This is used in Simpson and trapezoidal rule I think. A similar strategy is used for the Euler-Maclaurin sum formula, but this time we choose Bernoulli polynomials as primitives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x$ is fixed, so we can choose the factor $v$ to be equal to $t-x$.

Comment: But it is a definite integral, so $v = (t+c)\bigg\vert_0^x = x$, which is what I am confused. So there is no $(t-x)$ or $(x-t)$

Comment: Why do you evauate $v$ at the endpoints? Only $(t-x)f'(t)$ needs to be evaluated at the endpoints, which is already included in the calculation.

Comment: Then why not choose $v = t$ only?  because $\int \frac{dv}{dt} dt = \int 1 dt= t$

Comment: Yes, you can choose $v=t$, but it will not be convenient for what follows, I guess. The point is that you *can* also choose $v=t-x$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!